# Dark/Light theme assets qualifiers

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I have a very simple requirement to use Light/Dark themed images. I expected that a qualifier like

```
SomeImage.Theme-Light.png
```

or putting the image under a folder named Theme-Light

```
Theme-Light/SomeImage.png
```

would work, and it did, but only in the designer mode. As soon as I run the app, even though the required theme is properly set (on both app and page level so all the other ThemeResources get loaded correctly), wrong image gets loaded.

I know about workarounds to load different images for different themes, so that's not what I'm looking for. I am curious to know why this approach with qualifiers doesn't work in runtime? Is there a different name qualifier that should be used?

I read this article: "[How to name resources using qualifiers (XAML)"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965324.aspx) but it only shows how to name the assets with regards to high contrast support.

Comment: encountering this myself with the splashscreen image.  I want a white icon for dark theme on WP10, awhile another color icon for white theme

Comment: Using "contrast-white" and "contrast-black" should be the way to go, even e.g. Groove Music uses this approach. It works fine in my apps, the only exception is the splash screen.

Comment: @sibbl thank you for your suggestion, but this doesn't work unless the High Contrast is turned on. Filename is (for example, scale 150): LogoWithName.scale-150_contrast-black.png. Are you sure there's not something else you're setting to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

This aproach isn't as convenient as qualifiers, but it works.

Define in App.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
            <ImageSource x:Key="Logo">/Assets/Logo-White.png</ImageSource>
        </ResourceDictionary>

        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
            <ImageSource x:Key="Logo">/Assets/Logo-Blue.png</ImageSource>
        </ResourceDictionary>

        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="HighContrast">
            <ImageSource x:Key="Logo">/Assets/Logo-White.png</ImageSource>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then use

```
<Image Source="{ThemeResource Logo}"/>
```