# UWP How to get theme assets to respond to RequestedTheme

Tags: image, uwp, themes, assets

I have an app that saves user theme preferences and sets the RequestedTheme in the App constructor (I've done this so I can use Dark as the default, but users can select Light if they wish).  This has worked fine for my brush resources, but now I'm trying to add image assets for each theme, and the assets are matching the OS theme setting, rather than RequestedTheme.

Is there a way to override this?

I though this post might be helpful:

[Dark/Light theme assets qualifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35898368/dark-light-theme-assets-qualifiers)

But, when I follow the suggested answer, I can't seem to specify the theme for each resource without also specifying the scale.

For example, when I set the path to `/Assets/image.png`, I get the default behavior (assets match OS theme).  When I set the path to `/Assets/contrast-standard/theme-dark/scale-100/image.png` I get the theme I want, but only in scale-100.  When I set the path to  `/Assets/contrast-standard/theme-dark/image.png` no image is loaded.

Comment: The answer given in your referenced link for SO post is the solution you want. Please share your XAML/Resource dictionary to help you with the issue that you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I realized with the solution I was trying that my theme folders were no longer doing any good, so I just moved my scale-### folders directly to the Assets folder and deleted the theme folders.